# Future Updates - Handling High-Poly Sculpts Better?

Tags: sculpting, versions, polycount

(NOTE: I'm not sure if this is the place to ask; I couldn't seem to find an official Blender email address to contact regarding upcoming Blender updates.)

I recall reading that **ZBrush** has a method of rendering so many polygons on screen, so that models as high as 20 million triangles or higher don't slow down performance. However Blender starts to slow down when you're sculpting a model around 500,000 triangles, which is very frustrating to say the least.

Does anybody know if any future versions of Blender and/or planned updates will feature better high polygon count management, much like ZBrush?

Comment: This is not the right place to ask. Check the [Contacting Developers page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact) on the Blender Wiki.

Comment: Oh. I saw that it consists of a mailing list. Looks like too much hassle to deal with, honestly.